# Sitecore Ship returning 404 when trying to install update package

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

Ship returning 404 when trying to install update package.
Here is the script i'm trying for.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://mydomain/services/package/install" -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body @{"path"="@D:\Users\Parsh\Desktop\test.update";"DisableIndexing"=$true} -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 5000
```

And i'm getting below error.
`

```
    404 - NotFound
    The resource you have requested cannot be found.
    We're sorry :-(




  Graphics courtesy of the awesome Matthew Inman
At line:1 char:1

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://mydomain/services/package/inst ...
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
 eption
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`
```

I'm using .net framework 4.6.2 and Sitecore 8.2 initial release. also doubled checked all the configuration, everything looks fine,

Appreciate your support.

**Update : Attached screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error when browsing to `/services/about` on the server ([link to documentation](http://docs.sitecoreship.apiary.io/#reference/0/sitecoreship-information/about)). It's working on 8.1u3, but I heard there are issues on 8.2. It's also possible that if you have a custom 404 handler that it is being too aggressive and you need to ignore these routes.

Comment: I see Sitecore.Ship - version 0.4.0.0 , when i browse /services/about

Comment: Seems to be working ok then... where are you calling Ship from? Are you using Octopus deploy or something so the Powershell script is invoked on the server itself? Otherwise, did you enable remote `packageInstallation` and whitelist your server?

Comment: I have tried it in octopus first, did't worked. Then i tried toexecute the same command in local machine in the powershell. Did't worked. Attached the screenshot.

Comment: @jammykam Enabled remote packageInstallation and whitelist  server also.

Comment: Configuration looks correct to me, not sure if there are issues with 8.2, never used it on 8.2 myself.

Comment: Tried using Postman, Getting 404 status code again :(

Comment: @jammykam Tried publish api of Ship and it works fine, Not sure what is the problem with Install api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time to debug the issue as it was returning 404. Initially i thought that, resource itself not available.Later debugging the Sitecore.Ship framework i found that, 404 throwing bcz the **path** was not found. See screenshot below.

[image]

When i changed the location of the update file it worked.